# Python OOP: Practice passing results of one method into another

Tags: python, oop, methods, parameter-passing

This is just a general question for me concerning Python Object oriented programming. I have read many tutorials, but I struggle to make the jump of applying it to my own needs.
My question surrounds how to use OOP for certain basic tasks in Python.  OOP is probably not the best way to approach this problem, but this is mainly an example of OOP using data structures I am already familiar with.
I would like to take a CSV file with two items (in this case pets) and their respective combined prices, ex:

```
dog1,cat1,5.00

dog1,cat2,7.00

cat1,dog2,10.00

cat2,dog2,10.00

dog2,dog1,8.00

cat1,cat2,10.00
```

The following code is what I have so far, not great, but hopefully it is clear enough to explain my question.  Using a very basic OOP procedure (regardless of whether I need to or not), I am aiming to:

(1) Create instances for, and identify the required variables

(2) Using these variables, create a dictionary, and

(3) Pass the results of (2) into another method and parse this dictionary

Ultimately, the first method creates a dictionary like this:

{'cat__cat': [10.0], 'dog__cat': [7.0, 10.0, 10.0], 'dog__dog': [8.0]}

The second method then generates:

['dog__cat', 'dog__dog']

...since these are the 'cheaper' items.  What I would like to do, as listed at the end, is call both methods in a single line, using one to call the other.
How is this accomplished?

```
import sys
import numpy as np
infile=sys.argv[1]
class PriceParser:
    def __init__(self, linesplit):
        linesplit = line.split(",")
        self.Pet1 = linesplit[0]
        self.Pet2 = linesplit[1]
        self.price = linesplit[2].rstrip("\n")
        self.Pet1short = self.Pet1[0:3]
        self.Pet2short = self.Pet2[0:3]
        self.combo = self.Pet1short+"__"+self.Pet2short
        self.comborev = self.Pet2short+"__"+self.Pet1short
        self.PetSame = self.Pet1short+"__"+self.Pet1short
        #dictPetPrices = {}

    def PriceIdentifier (self):
        if self.Pet1short != self.Pet2short:
            if not self.comborev in dictPetPrices:
                if not self.combo in dictPetPrices:
                    dictPetPrices[self.combo]=[]
                dictPetPrices[self.combo]=[float(self.price)]
            else:
                dictPetPrices[self.comborev].append(float(self.price))
        elif self.Pet1short == self.Pet2short:
            if not self.PetSame in dictPetPrices:
                dictPetPrices[self.PetSame]=[]
            dictPetPrices[self.PetSame].append(float(self.price))
        return dictPetPrices

    def PriceSpectrum (self):

        Cheap = []
        for k,v in dictPetPrices.iteritems():

            for i in v:
                if float(i) <= 8:
                    Cheap.append(k)

        return Cheap


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(infile) as f:
        dictPetPrices = {}
        for line in f:

            A = PriceParser(line)
            B=A.PriceIdentifier()

    print B
    print A.PriceSpectrum()
    #What I would prefer to do (below), is pass one method into another, if for instance, I have multiple methods that need to be called
    #print A.PriceSpectrum(PriceIdentifier)
```

Comment: You made one big stew here.
What is your real problem? Bugs you mentioned are stopping two methods from getting results one from another???
Or what exactly??? 
A normal interaction between two methods/functions is not a question for Stack Overflow.
You should shorten your question, put your code in order and make it all more explicit.
Otherwise, you will get no answers or worst. 
Remove unnecessary parts of code.
Stack is problem solving forum, not a place to learn. Sorry if I am rood, but this is one of the kinder comments you'll get for such a question. I'll try to answer you.

Comment: I understand your point, however, I thought that with some example code it might allow more specific answers as opposed to generalized one's which are prevalent here and elsewhere.  That is the main issue for me in other tutorials, they are too simplistic.  I sick of learning how to make a triangle with OOP, or create bank account input/output.  Also, I was under the impression that problem solving and learning are the same?

Comment: As PC said, your code is a little bit badly structured.

Comment: As PC said, your code is a little bit badly structured.
Problem solving and learning are pretty the same, but there is no point in solving a problem that is already solved. Your question is just a bit unclear to have an answer out of the sleeve. You are doing things in your code that ARE NOT specific when programming OO. I don't want to fight, I want to help. Sorry for unfinished comment above, Mozilla did something funny.

Comment: You have one list refreshing after return, which never does nothing.
And you are calling a dictionary in for loop instead of using dict.keys(). This will raise TypeError. There is also attemt to return self.dictInterPatDist attribute and I don't see it initialized anywhere.
I'll take your code now and play around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much, much better! call_ident was an argument which caused self.PriceIdentifier() to be called. That was there to make sure that self.PriceIdentifier() was called if you didn't call it manually before. If you did call it before, you could say self.PriceSpectrum(0) to avoid calling it again.
If you wish to pass a function to another function, as I got it, you do it just like in C. Mutable objects in Python are accessed through references i.e. a pointer to an object is stored in a variable. At least you can look at it that way. That is why you have to copy a list when you pass it to function, unless you want an original list to change when you change it inside that function.
So:

```
def f (another_func): return another_func()
def g (): print "blah"
f(g)
```

You do the same with methods, as methods are only functions with additional argument self, which is a reference to the instance you wish it to be refering to. In most other languages, it is called this.

Try this as well:

```
def callme (func, *args, **kwargs):
    print "I will call", func
    print "With arguments:", args
    print "And keyword arguments:", kwargs
    func(*args, **kwargs)

def dateandtime (date, time, zone=None):
    print "The date:", date
    print "The time:", time
    print "Zone:", zone

callme(dateandtime, "01.01.1881. AC", "00:00:00")
```

Try adding zone to see what will happen.
If this is what you want, then see with which questions Stack connected yours now the Q is clearer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience.

for methods it would be like this however (Right?)

A=PriceParser()

A.PriceSpectrum(A.PriceIdentifier)

Comment: Yes, exactly! Method is a function inside a class, there fore inside an instance as well.
A is your instance, and you wish to calculate identifier for this instance. You can pass a method of other instance, or ordinary function, PriceParser.PriceSpectrum() will not care what calls, just that it gets right results.

Comment: As you are still in process of learning OOP, here is a concept most don't get after years of OOPing.
Now, we did instantiate A, but when you say A.PriceSpectrum(), that is still PriceParser.PriceSpectrum().
Instantiation does not copy methods. Imagine what memory mess would it be if it did. Instead, a reference to the instance (stuff before a dot, eg. A) is passed as argument self.
You can do it manualy. I.e. A.PriceIdentifier() and PriceParser.PriceIdentifier(A) is the same thing.

Comment: I tell you all this because we are discussing here unseen Python pointers and to warn you for future.
If you have some attributes that are mutable objects which are not initiated inside a constructor, but only in class, and you change them in your instances, all instances of the same class will see these changes. Sometimes it is desirable, but sometimes can mess your head and code. Exactly like a list in a function argument. Same mechanism.

Comment: Most high level OO programming languages function like that.
This also means, that you can define a method inside a class without self argument.
But you will not be able to call it as from an instance, just from a class.
Call to instance method will always try to add its reference in first argument.
If you do not have self, you will get a too many arguments error.
One example is dict.fromkeys([1,2,3,4,5]) will work, while dict.keys() won't until you gave it an instance: dict.keys(dict()) or dict().keys().

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

inputstr = """\
dog1,cat1,5.00
dog1,cat2,7.00
cat1,dog2,10.00
cat2,dog2,10.00
dog2,dog1,8.00
cat1,cat2,10.00"""

class PriceParser:
    def __init__(self, line):
        linesplit = line.strip().split(",")
        self.Pet1 = linesplit[0]
        self.Pet2 = linesplit[1]
        self.price = linesplit[2]
        self.Pet1short = self.Pet1[0:3]
        self.Pet2short = self.Pet2[0:3]
        self.combo = self.Pet1short+"__"+self.Pet2short
        self.comborev = self.Pet2short+"__"+self.Pet1short
        self.PetSame = self.Pet1short+"__"+self.Pet1short
        self.dictPetPrices = {}

    def PriceIdentifier (self):
        if self.Pet1short != self.Pet2short:
            if not self.comborev in self.dictPetPrices:
                if not self.combo in self.dictPetPrices:
                    self.dictPetPrices[self.combo]=[]
                self.dictPetPrices[self.combo]=[float(self.price)]
            else:
                self.dictPetPrices[self.comborev].append(float(self.price))
        elif self.Pet1short == self.Pet2short:
            if not self.PetSame in self.dictPetPrices:
                self.dictPetPrices[self.PetSame]=[]
            self.dictPetPrices[self.PetSame].append(float(self.price))
        return self.dictPetPrices

    def PriceSpectrum (self, call_ident=True):
        if call_ident: self.PriceIdentifier()
        Percentiles = []
        for k in self.dictPetPrices.keys():
            self.dictPetPrices[k].sort()
            a = np.asarray(self.dictPetPrices[k])
            Q1 = np.percentile(a, 1)
            Q25 = np.percentile(a, 25)
            Q50 = np.percentile(a, 50)
            Q75 = np.percentile(a, 75)
            Q90 = np.percentile(a, 90)
            Percentiles.extend([Q1,Q50,Q75,Q90])
        return Percentiles

if __name__ == '__main__':              
    for line in inputstr.split("\n"):
        A = PriceParser(line)
        print A.PriceIdentifier()
        print A.PriceSpectrum()
```

This yields following results:

```
{'dog__cat': [5.0]}
[5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
{'dog__cat': [7.0]}
[7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0]
{'cat__dog': [10.0]}
[10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]
{'cat__dog': [10.0]}
[10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]
{'dog__dog': [8.0]}
[8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0]
{'cat__cat': [10.0]}
[10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]
```

Please, explain what result would you like to have.
Did you mean to make one array of all prices, then, you have to parse all input inside a class or use some other structure.
You parse only one line here.
Or, you can have PriceSpectrum() taking argument, a list, which would then accumulate all prices or something like that.

As you can see, methods are communicating internally using attributes.
Milion arguments to a function is stuff for structural programming.
Leave this concept out of any OO. Methods should take only arguments needed for asking something or giving something that is not already available to an instance.
Please explain everything according to my code. What I got wrong and what did you wish to achieve. Is the communication from your question satisfying, or are you aiming for some special sort.
I really hope this helps. At least, no errors now.

Comment: Thanks so much Dalen.  I did not mean to sound defensive in the previous post, it was not my intension.  Due to your constructive criticisms I see where the confusion is now.  I have re-written the question which is hopefully clearer now.  I believe you are one small step away from answering this.  Thanks again.  BTW, in your example, what is call_ident?

Comment: I added another answer because it was too long for comment. I hope this does it!

Answer (score 0):

You have some of the right ideas but your code is badly structured.  When you call `PriceParser(linesplit)` you are actually calling `PriceParser.__init__(self,linesplit)`.  This is the right place to initialize member variables.  So move the first bunch of code from `PriceIdentifier`, down to the ## comment, into `__init__`.  This will fix the problem of undefined variable names.

I don't understand what you are trying to do in the code after the ## comment.  It would be a good idea to put your questions into the text rather than burying them in the code comments.  By the way, the line `self.Percentiles[:]=[]` is unreachable (follows a return).

Comment: Thanks PC. I am only hoping this code is good enough to illustrate my concerns.  My apologies if it is not. After I moved the code around as you said I get this error:
print A.PriceIdentifier(linesplit,Pet1short,Pet2short,combo,comborev,PetSame,price)
NameError: name 'Pet1short' is not defined

After the ## portion you specified, the resulting dict should resemble:
{'cat__dog': ['7.00','10.00','10.00'],'cat__cat':['10.00'],etc}
Then I simply want to parse this dictionary somehow.  Could be any parse, the point is really to pass method into another.
Thanks for the clarification request.

Comment: Indeed `Pet1Short` is undefined.  It's the name of a member variable of class `PriceParser`, but you're trying to access it like a global.  So you need an instance of PriceParser, which is `A`.  Therefore `A.Pet1Short` is a valid variable.  However, you don't need to pass this variable to a member method of PriceParser, since within that method it can be accessed as `self.Pet1Short`.  None of this has anything to do with passing the result of one method to another, which is your original stated question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer you according to my interpretation of what is happening in your code.
I can tell you as much (at a first glance):

```
...
def __init__ (self, ...):
    self.Pet1 = Pet1
```

Raises NameError because global variable Pet1, which you're trying to put into self.Pet1 does not exist.
Yes, the thing would work if Pet1 is initialized outside the class, and before you instantiate the class, of course.

```
# If you wanted just to initialize self.Pet1 then give it a value like: "Pet1", "" or None; inside __init__() constructor.
    self.Pet1 = ""
```

Your class is a *parser*, then *parse* your line inside a constructor, and put values into atributes.
If you do that, there is no need for other methods to take arguments (more than self), you use these attributes to access needed values.
You will then have something like:

```
for line in f:
    A = PriceParser(line)
    print "Cat1 costs:", A.price("cat1") # Or whatever you want
    print "Avg price of all dogs is:", A.PricesMean("dog")

# Use constructor __init__() to do all the job (splitting, putting into attrs, etc.).
# Do not use tons of arguments in methods. What if zoo-shop adds rabbits the next day?
# If you wish to have all kind of pets covered, use one attr with a dictionary to keep values for each, not a new attribute for each pet.
# If you really wish to have an attribute per pet, use an instance scope variable container self.__dict__
# For instance:
def add_doggy (self, dog_name, dog_colour, dog_price):
    self.__dict__["dog_"+dog_name] = (dog_colour, dog_price)
# Then the following is possible:
A.add_doggy("Rex", "black", 30):
print "Rex costs:", A.dog_Rex[1]

# But this, and all other methods you can use to do same/similar things are more in field of meta programming for which, I think, you are not ready yet.
```

Please edit your question as I commented.
Start learning OOP with tutorials with examples, try doing some serious things, eg. program a GUI using wxPython, it will help you get the hang of it.